# Test cases for Prisma's Interactive Transactions

Tags: node.js, testing, transactions, prisma

I have a use case where people can purchase an item concurrently and there is only 100 of them. I ended up using [Prisma's Interactive Transactions](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/performance-and-optimization/prisma-client-transactions-guide#interactive-transactions) to avoid a race condition and also roll back if an error occured.

Snippets

```
await prisma.$transaction(async (tx) => {
    await tx.user.create({
      data: {
        ....
      },
    });

    // decrement
    const item = await tx.item.update({
      data: {
        balance: {
          decrement: 1,
        },
      },
    });

    if (item.balance < 0) {
      throw new Error('cant go below zero');
    }
  });
```

Testing manually with postman under one account seems to be working fine. If I want to simulate multiple users purchasing concurrently, how can I write some unit/integration testing for this? Any guidance would be helpful.